# How can I attach an action event to a date picker in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to execute a method in the controller when I select a date. I have this:

```
<input class="form-control col-sm-5" asp-action="SetTimes" asp-for="Date" type="date" value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")" />
```

The asp-action="SetTimes" was suggested by another student. I wanted it to call the method "SetTimes()" in the controller whenever I pick a date, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asp-action` is invalid in the input datetype field. Instead, you can do this in the js onchange function.

```
<input class="form-control col-sm-5" onchange="SetTime(this.value)" asp-for="Date" type="date" value="@DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")" />


@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        function SetTime(value) {
            window.location.href = "Controller/Action?Date=" + value;
        }
    </script>
}
```